# How to combine Date and Time WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to combine Date under form ("dd.MM.yyy")and Time and insert into one datetime object :

Exemple: 
Date 13/10/2017 and TIME : 10:30 -> the combine Date result: 13/10/2017 10:30

XAML:

```
       //DATE ("dd.MM.yyy")
  <DatePicker  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"         
        SelectedDate="{Binding DeliveryDate, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,NotifyOnValidationError=True ,TargetNullValue=''}"/>


        //TIME 
   <TextBox  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"  >
                <TextBox.Text >
                    <Binding Path="Time" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" Mode="TwoWay" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:DateTimeValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public DateTime DeliveryDate;
    private TimeSpan time;
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set
        {
            time = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }


     public DateViewModel()
    {   saveDate = new RelayCommand<string>(SaveDateFunction);
        DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.Date ;

      }

    public void SaveDateFunction(string obj)          
     {
      DateTime combined = DeliveryDate.Add(Time);
     }
```

I have error result : 13/10/2017 00:00:00 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following signature for the SaveDateFunction method

```
public void SaveDateFunction(string obj)          
{
   DateTime combined = DeliveryDate.AddMilliseconds(Time.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

can try the working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K4sHUD)

```
DateTime d=DateTime.Now.Date;
TimeSpan t = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
DateTime combined = d.AddMilliseconds(t.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Time is not set but you don't get `NullReferenceException` because `TimeSpan` is a structure and has a default value instead of `null`.

Value is not being passed from the UI to your property because you need a converter. I am sure that you can see errors in an output window.

```
public class StringToTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Your code here
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`DeliveryDate` is a field, not a property, so it's binding is not working too.